# Need to restrict added Information near product Price in Magento

Tags: magento, product

I am working in a Magento store, I want to add some information related to price near price in product view page. So I added the same near price in price.phtml file. But the problem was that added information was comes with the price in all the blocks where product price was called.

For example that information was also comes in product list page, product compare and latest products. I want to restrict it and show the information in product view page only.

Thanks,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the `<catalog_product_view>` handle, add your additional information in its own block to the *catalog/product/view.phtml* template right after where ever the price block content renders. Or, do the same, but add the `getChildHtml` call to the price block.